# How do i fix "ls > less" in CentOs

Tags: linux, command-line

How can i fix "ls > less" in Cent-Os. I made this mistake in the process of learning Linux.
Being new to the platform and Os and learning from a manual i read the command in a context and thought to see what it does, now after some research i'm still unable to fix it, can someone please help me?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you did a `ls > less` in some local directory, you've just created a file called `less`, which contains a listing of the current directory. No big deal… just delete it:

```
rm ./less
```

Unless, of course, you were in `/usr/bin` *and* had root privileges. Because then you overwrote your system's `less` command. Then, you should restore it from a backup. If you don't have a backup, you should do a system reinstallation, but of course backing up your home directory and important configuration before you wipe your drive. In any case you should take a note never to run under root privileges when you're not 100% sure what you're doing.

If you're not up for a reinstallation and don't have a backup, you can use another pager instead of `less`, e.g. the not as nice `more`, by running `cp /usr/bin/{more,less}`. But that's really not recommended.